# ContentProvider project as library for other projects

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, android-context

I had read the documentation of `ContentProvider` and quite good number of tutorials\questions but seems there's gap in my head about how could I use the `ContentProvider` project; the first project which is the `ContentProvider` from [TutorialPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_content_providers.htm) and it's working fine, I added to my **demo project** the following statement `android:sharedUserId="com.example.mycontentprovider` to my **AndroidManifest.XML** to access the shared DB I had there. Now I want to use the *CRUD* functions and I'm not sure how to do this, I found one of  solutions here is to do such statement
 `Context friendContext = this.createPackageContext("com.example.mycontentprovider",Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);`

Another solution been found is to initialize **Intent** and start activity and I did as the following:

```
Intent openMyContentProvider = new Intent("com.example.mycontentprovider",MainActivity.this);
```

and it gives me error for the arguments and though not sure how to proceed after starting new Activity; Any further requirements or codes will be provided and thanks in advance for your  response.

Comment: use a ContentResolver

Comment: Thanks pskink, will check it right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html) to **read** data from the content provider, with the advantage of getting updates when the data in the database changes.

Use [ContentResolver](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/content-resolvers-and-content-providers.html) for **read**, **insert**, **update** and **delete** operations. And there is [AsyncQueryHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncQueryHandler.html) to help make handling asynchronous ContentResolver queries easier, you can use its on*Complete() callbacks to let the user know the operation was successful. [Using AsyncQueryHandler](http://www.seal.io/2013/02/how-to-use-asyncqueryhandler_20.html)

Comment: Quite useful, I trying now **ContentResolver** since I need the CRUD operations; receiving logcat error will try to resolve them and later will try to check AsyncQueryHandler or the CursorLoader. Appreciate your response.